# Incorrect number of type parameters in reference class MyClass<F,T> - Generic entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics

I've got the following generic abstract class:

```
public abstract class MyClass<F, T>
    where TCurrencyFrom : Book
    where TCurrencyTo : Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual F First{ get; set; }
    public virtual T Second { get; set; }
}
```

And I got 3 classes which implement this class like:

```
public class Implementation1 : MyClass<BookType1, BookType2>
{
}

public class Implementation2 : MyClass<BookType2, BookType1>
{
}
```

Now I got an "EntityTypeConfiguration" for those which looks like:

```
public class MyClassConfiguration<TMyClass> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TMyClass> where TMyClass: MyClass
{
    public MyClassConfiguration()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

And try to use those like:

```
public class Implementation1Map : MyClassConfiguration<Implementation1> 
{
    public Implementation1Map ()
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

But then I get the following error:

> Incorrect number of type parameters in reference class MyClass

How can I solve this problem and make sure I have a generic approach on the EntityTypeConfigurations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately this is tricky with .NET generics.

If `MyClassConfiguration` doesn't actually care about the type arguments, you might want to create a non-generic interface:

```
public interface IMyClass
{
    // Any members of MyClass<,> which don't rely on the type arguments,
    // e.g. the Id property
}
```

Then make `MyClass<,>` implement `IMyClass`:

```
// Type parameters renamed to make the type constraints sensible...
public abstract class MyClass<TCurrencyFrom, TCurrencyTo> : IMyClass
    where TCurrencyFrom : Book
    where TCurrencyTo : Book
```

And change the type constraint for `MyClassConfiguration`:

```
public class MyClassConfiguration<TMyClass> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TMyClass>
    where TMyClass: IMyClass
```

(Obviously you'll want to give `IMyClass` a more useful name...)

Alternatively, just make `MyClassConfiguration` generic in three type parameters:

```
public class MyClassConfiguration<TMyClass, TCurrencyFrom, TCurrencyTo>
    : EntityTypeConfiguration<TMyClass>
    where TMyClass: MyClass<TCurrencyFrom, TCurrencyTo>
    where TCurrencyFrom : Book
    where TCurrencyTo : Book

public class Implementation1Map
    : MyClassConfiguration<Implementation1, BookType1, BookType2> 

public class Implementation2Map
    : MyClassConfiguration<Implementation2, BookType2, BookType1>
```

It's ugly, but it'll work.

Comment: what  about   where TCurrencyFrom : Book  
    where TCurrencyTo : Book is this correct ??

Comment: @K.B: Edited to rename the type parameters in the obvious way.

Comment: And this isn't possible without the interface? Because how I see it the interface doesn't really add anything. It would only be used to "fix" the problem.

Comment: @Julian: Well you could make it a non-generic abstract class which the generic class derives from if you want. But you can't express a constraint of "`TMyClass : MyClass<,>` but I don't care what the type arguments are".

Comment: @JonSkeet But now I can't use the books within the MyClassConfiguration.

Comment: @Julian: Well they depend on the type arguments. Given the constraints on the type parameters, you could expose getters of type `Book` within the non-generic interface. Alternatively, just make MyClassConfiguration have three type parameters (so include the from/to parameters) - I'll edit to show that.

Comment: @JonSkeet: I like this solution alot more. Although one little thing is that I need to specify the books twice now. In the domain and within the configuration. It would be nice if there was a way to use the generic types of the implementation instead of specifying them again.

Comment: @Julian: You could probably do that with type inference, by creating a static generic method in a non-generic type, like `Tuple.Create`.